SAFE Protocol not recognize contracts deployed using SafeProxy on Base
Safe wallet protocol-kit is not working on Base. We are using Proxy 1.3 and Safe 1.3.0+L2
https://app.safe.global/settings/setup?safe=base:0x1EDc8bD487b35442D987F75660594c4E6bA3D51A
As you can see the app recognizes it normally. But when we try to create a transaction using protocol-kit it returns the following error.
Contract-transaction-hash= 0xa793bd83b720b8135ca9d8d485071f789ad218b65ce1a668f5b9f321b099668b
does not match provided contract-tx-hash=
0x3d27528ffe131b4ab871d4365901e1e76bad5bd80f4f24e1bcd7206b73f26387
Is there a way to ignore this error? Our users are unable to use our app. We need that specific versions of proxy and Safe because we need the clone functionality.
These are the packages we are using:
"@safe-global/api-kit": "^2.4.4"
"@safe-global/protocol-kit": "^4.0.4"
"@safe-global/safe-apps-provider": "^0.18.3"
"@safe-global/safe-apps-sdk": "^9.1.0"
"@safe-global/safe-core-sdk-types": "^5.0.3"

Could you please provide the code that you use that leads to this error? I would also update dependencies as the latest version for api-kit is 2.5.2, for the protocol-kit it is 5.0.2 and the safe-core-sdk-types has been replaced by types-kit. Thanks in advance

Actually the issue was a wrong configuration for the backend endpoint. I was using Base Sepolia endpoint for Base.

Actually the issue was a wrong configuration for the backend endpoint. I was using Base Sepolia endpoint for Base.
